# best way to read log file part by part

Tags: php

1. I have log file (max size 50Mb) in which every second written user GET request with parameters (nginx make it).
2. I have cron php script, which starts every minute, should read next part of log file, calculate data and insert data in statistic mysql database.

What is the best way to read log file part by part every minute?

Comment: Why don't you edit nginx to make smaller files? Seems much easier.

Comment: I can set it up, but what the best way to read log file part by part every minute use cron php script

Comment: Maybe if you have access to `exec`, call `tail -n` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read log file on regular way, something like this:

```
$myFile = "log.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);
$last_line = 0;
@$last_line = file_get_contents('log-last-line.txt');

$i = 0;
foreach($lines as $line){
    $i++;
    if($i >= $last_line){
        //this lines are new, save them in database
    }
}
file_put_contents('log-last-line.txt', count($lines));
```

You can write to "log-last-line.txt" last line from log.